# Create New C++ Class

Tags: beginner, bash, template

I'm currently developing a new version of [ExpressGenGen](https://github.com/JaDogg/ExpressGenGen/tree/TDD) Using [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). While I'm rewriting the new version of my **Code Generator Generator**.
I'm using its [old version](https://github.com/JaDogg/ExpressGenGen) to generate code to be used by the new version. 
This is how I'm creating new classes: when a new class is created,
it will generate a `.cpp` and `.h` file and then add them to `CMakeLists.txt`,
and also `TestHelper.h` is updated with new headers.

**What I want reviewed are the bash scripts.** (You are also welcome to review the ExpressGenGen templates)

### Bash Scripts

#### gen

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ..
cat Samples/template_bash_CMakeLists.txt | xgengen bash | bash - > CMakeLists.txt
cat Samples/template_bash_TestHelper.txt | xgengen bash | bash - > Tests/TestHelper.h
```

#### new_class

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Create New Class'
echo '--------------------------'
echo 'Type Class Name : '
read _class
# convert Upper Camel case to header guard, ex: NewClass -> _NEW_CLASS_H_
_guard=`echo $_class | sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\)/_\1/g' | awk '{printf toupper($0)} END{printf "_H_";}'`
# export the variables so they are visible to the child shell
export guard=$_guard
export class=$_class
cat template_bash_CPP.txt | xgengen bash | bash - > "../Src/$class.cpp"
cat template_bash_H.txt | xgengen bash | bash - > "../Src/$class.h"
./gen
```

### Templates

#### template_bash_CMakeLists.txt

```
project(ExpressGenGen)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
include_directories($ENV{BOOST_ROOT} $ENV{LUA_ROOT} $ENV{GMOCK_HOME}/include $ENV{GMOCK_HOME}/gtest/include .)
link_directories($ENV{LUA_ROOT} $ENV{BOOST_ROOT}/stage/lib $ENV{GMOCK_HOME}/build $ENV{GMOCK_HOME}/build/gtest) 
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAXE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wpedantic -std=gnu++11")

set(sources 
$$$find . -name '*.cpp' | sed 's/\.\//  /'
    $$$find . -name '*.h' | sed 's/\.\//  /'
  WindowsRsrc/WindowsRes.rc)
add_executable(xgengen ${sources})
target_link_libraries(xgengen lua)
target_link_libraries(xgengen boost_program_options)
target_link_libraries(xgengen pthread)
target_link_libraries(xgengen gmock)
target_link_libraries(xgengen gtest)
```

#### template_bash_CPP.txt

```
//--------------------------------------------
// Definition
#include "{$$$class$$}.h"
//--------------------------------------------
// Uses
//
//--------------------------------------------

{$$$class$$}::{$$$class$$}()
{

}

//--------------------------------------------
```

#### template_bash_H.txt

```
#ifndef {$$$guard$$}
#define {$$$guard$$}

//--------------------------------------------
// Has
//
//--------------------------------------------
// Inherits
//
//--------------------------------------------
// Uses
//
//--------------------------------------------

class {$$$class$$} {
public:
    {$$$class$$}();
    virtual ~{$$$class$$}() {}

private:
};

//-------------------------------------------

#endif // {$$$guard$$}
```

#### template_bash_TestHelper.txt

```
//--------------------------------------------
// TestHelper
//
// This header is basically an include all type helper for Test*.cpp files
// therefore greatly reducing duplication
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-local-typedefs"
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
// AutoGenerated
$$$find Src -name "*.h" | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/#include \"\.\.\/\1\"/g'
// End AutoGenerated
//--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: **Note: I cannot fix the indentation**

Comment: @janos The line after `$$$find . -name '*.cpp' | sed 's/\.\//  /'`. See http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5063/something-breaks-my-indentation/5064#5064

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Use input redirection instead of `cat | ...`

Instead of `cat somefile | somecommand`, you should use input redirection, for example:

```
xgengen bash < Samples/template_bash_CMakeLists.txt | bash - > CMakeLists.txt
```

The advantage of this is that you're running one fewer process (no more `cat`).

#### Use modern style command substitution `$(...)`

Don't use old style `` `...` `` command substitution.
Use the modern and better `$(...)` style.

#### Simplify `sed` + `awk` pipelines when possible

This looks very complicated, and it's suspicious to have both `sed` and `awk` in the same pipeline:

```
echo $_class | sed -e 's/\([A-Z]\)/_\1/g' | awk '{printf toupper($0)} END{printf "_H_";}'
```

You can simplify using a single `awk` command:

```
echo $_class | awk '{gsub("[A-Z]", "_\&"); printf toupper($0) "_H_"}'
```

#### Use here-strings instead of `echo | ...`

Similar to using input redirection instead of `cat | ...`,
in Bash it's better to replace `echo | ...` with here-strings using `<<<`,
rewriting the above example as:

```
awk '{gsub("[A-Z]", "_\&"); printf toupper($0) "_H_"}' <<< $_class
```

#### Use alternative regex pattern separator to improve readability

When a regular expression pattern contains `/`,
using such patterns with the `s///` operator becomes tedious and hard to read,
because of the escapes.
To improve readability, it's often good to use an alternative pattern separator.
So for example instead of this:

```
sed 's/\.\//  /'
```

You can do this instead to avoid escaping `/`:

```
sed 's|\./|  |'
```

The benefit is more obvious when you have multiple `/` in the pattern.
In this example the difference might be negligible.

#### Simplify regex

The `s///` here can be simplified:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)/#include \"\.\.\/\1\"/g'
```

To this:

```
sed -e 's/.*/#include "..\/&"/'
```

That is:

- No need to capture `.*` in `\(...\)`, you can access the matched string directly with `&`
- No need to escape `.` in replacement, as it has no special meaning there
- No need to escape `"` within single-quoted strings in Bash
- Since the pattern matches the entire line, no need for the `g` flag

Comment: This is a very good answer with many interesting suggestions.

Comment: `$()` may be better, but to the best of my knowledge it still isn't supported by the default shell on certain System V derived systems.  As I see no other reason the scripts above need to be tied to bash rather than *any* Bourne shell, I'd suggest sticking with backticks and using `#!/bin/sh` rather than relying on bash being installed, which it may not be in some systems.

Comment: @Jules that won't work considering that `xgengen` generate bash code. But what you said gave me an idea that I should make it generate `sh` code as well.